# How do i solve this?

Tags: xacro

[image: Rosanswers logo]

xacro: Traditional processing is deprecated. Switch to --inorder processing!
To check for compatibility of your document, use option --check-order.
For more infos, see http://wiki.ros.org/xacro#Processing_Order
resource not found: create_description
ROS path [0]=/opt/ros/kinetic/share/ros
ROS path [1]=/home/jhdeanda/catkin_ws/src
ROS path [2]=/opt/ros/kinetic/share
XacroException('resource not found:',)
when processing file: /home/jhdeanda/catkin_ws/src/kobuki/turtlebot_description/urdf/turtlebot_library.urdf.xacro
included from: /home/jhdeanda/catkin_ws/src/kobuki/turtlebot_description/robots/kobuki_hexagons_kinect.urdf.xacro
while processing /home/jhdeanda/catkin_ws/src/kobuki/turtlebot_gazebo/launch/includes/kobuki.launch.xml:
Invalid  tag: Cannot load command parameter [robot_description]: command [/opt/ros/kinetic/share/xacro/xacro.py '/home/jhdeanda/catkin_ws/src/kobuki/turtlebot_description/robots/kobuki_hexagons_kinect.urdf.xacro'] returned with code [2].

Param xml is 
The traceback for the exception was written to the log file

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/259750/how-do-i-solve-this?/) by [jhdeanda](https://answers.ros.org/users/30097/jhdeanda/) on ROS Answers with karma: 11 on 2017-04-20

Post score: -1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Find wherever your robot description is launched. Maybe you could grep for it:

```
grep -r "robot_description" *
```

Then change the command slightly:

```
<param name="robot_description" command="$(find xacro)/xacro '$(find robot_description)/urdf/my_robot.urdf.xacro'" />
```

to

```
<param name="robot_description" command="$(find xacro)/xacro '--inorder' '$(find robot_description)/urdf/my_robot.urdf.xacro'" />
```

---

Originally posted by [AndyZe](https://answers.ros.org/users/21281/andyze/) with karma: 2331 on 2017-04-20

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [raequin](https://answers.ros.org/users/33937/raequin/) on 2018-03-23**:
Can you explain the difference between traditional processing and inorder?